# Running scheduled methods on tomcat

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat6

I am trying to set up a method that will be automatically run by the server at a specific time. For instance, a method that sends out emails to contacts every Friday at 9.00 am. I have seen methods that are run when the server is first started and was wondering if what I want to do is possible. If it is possible, can someone point me to where I can start reading up how to do this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent library [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) which can help you create scheduled tasks within your application. See e.g., the [Job Scheduling in Java](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/quartz.html?page=2) guide by o'reilly.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it manually (and not use specific tools like Quartz), you could use a [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), which would be created when the application is deployed and canceled when the application is destroyed, using a [ServletContextListener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) declared in your web.xml.

Be prepared for additional complexity if your application is clustered on multiple servers, though.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend using Quartz as Johan already suggested, it is a well-established solution for job scheduling in Java applications and also allows for central job storage in a database and clustering of multiple Tomcat instances.

In case your web application uses the Spring Framework, you could instead use [the built-in scheduling support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) instead.